# Can you raise the domain functional level to windows server 2016 and have DFS running on windows server 2012 r2?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, windows-server-2016, dfs

I have 2 DC's that are both Windows Server 2016.

We have one DFS server running Windows Server 2012 R2 but all of the namespaces are 2008 compatability mode.

Our Domain Functional Level is at Windows Server 2012 R2. If I were to raise it to Windows Server 2016 will that have any impact on our DFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't as the two compatibility modes are separate (DFS and AD that is).  We did the same transition from 2012 up to 2016.  If you leave the DFS server in 2008, it should still work with a 2016 Domain Level.  Just do not change one of your DFS servers to a higher compatibility mode without doing the other.

Comment: I did raise the Domain functional level and our DFS server stopped working responding. After a restart, it still only gave a black screen. I then restarted both DCs and the DFS server and it has been running without a hitch since.